# I can't get this <div> element to sit inside the other <div>?

Tags: css, html

I have two divs, one inside of the other. The "innerdiv" is not behaving as I expect it to. It is not sitting on the inside of the "maindiv" on the right side. Will someone please explain why?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D9RsQ/

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "maindiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </p>
        <div class = "innerdiv">
            <p>This is innerdiv content</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
html {
    height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #004c99);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #004c99);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #004c99);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #004c99);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #004c99);
}

p {
    font-family:"Arial Black";
    line-height:120%;
}
div.maindiv {
    width:90%;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:rgb(220,220,220);
    border-right: solid black 2px;
    border-left: solid black 2px;
}
div.innerdiv {
    width:100px;
    float:right;
    background-color:rgb(100,100,100);
}
```

Comment: Remove `float:right` from `div.innerdiv` and the second div will be "inside" the first div.

Comment: try to add overflow:hidden to maindiv

Comment: Set `overflow: auto` in the outer div CSS.Set `overflow: auto` in the outer div CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/39Rtv/)

Comment: removing the `float:right;` does fix the problem of the `innerdiv` being outside of the `maindiv` but the problem is that it is on the left side of the `maindiv`, not the right. I want it to hug the right side of the innerdiv and start at the top.

Comment: Thanks mbratch, but how to I make it start at the top of the maindiv?

Comment: Just move it to the top of the `maindiv` in the html like so: http://jsfiddle.net/39Rtv/1/

Answer (score 5):

You need to use one of the numerous [`clearfix`](http://css-tricks.com/containers-dont-clear-floats/) tricks on the parent. For instance:

```
div.maindiv:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

[**View on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4nNy/)

For more details on clearfix tricks, check out [Chris Coyier's fine summary.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

And if you want the right box to appear in the top right, simply place it in your Html before the paragraph of the main div:

```
<div class = "maindiv">
  <div class = "innerdiv">
    <p>This is innerdiv content</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

[**View on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4nNy/1/)

#### Clearfixing? What is this madness?

To explain what's going on here (and what else it might effect), let me start by explaining what a float is.

In technical terms, a float is an element that's been removed from the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow). The normal flow just refers to elements that behave like `block` or `inline` boxes. There are a number of things you can do to remove an element from the normal flow. Setting `position: absolute;` is one example. And, as I said before, floats are another example.

So how does a float behave? Well, it takes up horizontal space but not vertical space.

This is ideal for what I imagine to be one of the intended uses of floats: images next to paragraphs. This allows for a floated element to display like this:

[image: Float]

*Image source: w3c CSS2 Specs*

That image shows a common layout in articles, and is only possible when the floated element doesn't push the next paragraph down. Hence, floats are ignored when it comes to the vertical format of a page.

That image comes from the specs themselves, which is why I think the authors of the specification intended floats to be used for this purpose.

Consequently, by using floats for layouts we might be forcing them to do something they weren't necessarily intended for. But this is no cause for worry, because Css is still relatively new and we tend to need to do this a lot. Better formatting systems are coming up soon (namely, [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) and [grid layouts](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-grid/))

But yes, when it comes to layouts we don't want the behavior in the above image. We want the element to hug a side while also taking up vertical space. And while floats don't behave like this by default, we can force them to. And, when you do that, it's called `clearfixing`.

I'll explain the method I used above: using the `clear` property. This property allows you to restrict floats on either side of the element. `clear: both;` prevents floats on either side.

We apply this property to the `:after` pseudoelement of the parent, so that it doesn't appear in our markup but still renders in the browser. And voila! We've successfully clearfixed!

For more on the clear property, I refer you to the [excellent MDN article on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

Comment: Thanks, this works, but would you mind explaining what exactly this does? What else might it affect?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make the `innerdiv` display starting at the **TOP** of the maindiv?

Comment: To your first question: the first link in the post ([also here](http://css-tricks.com/containers-dont-clear-floats/)) explains it in non-technical terms. I'll edit my post with the technical terms of why the parent doesn't add the float's height to it. To your second question: see the second part of my answer? Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Just set `overflow: auto` on `div.mainDiv`

http://jsfiddle.net/77NEF/